# Keep an element always appear and unable to remove?

Tags: jquery

I have question. I want my customers cannot remove footer credits in my theme like :

```
<div class='tenten' style='visibility:visible !important; display:block !important; opacity:1 !important'> This theme is designed by abc.com </div>
```

I want it always appear, and if it is disappeared by any reason, it will redirect to my site: cba.com

I use Jquery to keep it but if it is inside any other elements. For example :

```
<div class="sixsix">
<div class='tenten' style='visibility:visible !important; display:block !important; opacity:1 !important'> This theme is designed by abc.com </div>
</div>
```

Then it is easy to remove it by using css:

```
.sixsix {display:none}
```

My question is:

How to make it always appear?

Comment: There is no way to force it to always be there if someone has control over the styles. And there is more ways to hide it than just setting visibility, display, opacity.

Comment: @epascarello: I will control it with encrypted code.

Comment: Does not matter... I can write any CSS to change it.

Comment: Best thing you can do is **include user agreement and require users to keep it there.**  Should someone remove it, you can do something legally. But there is not much else you can do about this.

Comment: how about using an `iframe` ?

Comment: @Be0wulf and I can hide the iframe, just like the div. Unless the OP codes it in such a way all the content is in the iframe and wants to host it. [aka Google +1, Facebook like]

Comment: I want give my customers free version with encrypted code. So I need use Jquery to keep footer credit. If possible, can you give me the solution?

Comment: There is NO solution...that is the problem.

Comment: I think I will combine code to keep footer credit with main js in my site and then I will encrypt it. So any editing is not allowed.

Comment: This shows you don't know how browsers work. Don't waste your time, you can't _lock_ DOM elements.

Comment: ok. No need to say more. Thank for all suggestions.